# Android Action Bar Responding to users

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am having issues with some methods with my app in android. I'm trying to respond to a button pressed by a user. Here is the method:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;

        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }     
 }
```

I was looking at the docs provided from google about this and it says those methods should be called depending on the user's action. Am I missing something?

The error messages area:

Error:(42, 17) error: cannot find symbol method openSearch()

Error:(46, 17) error: cannot find symbol method openSettings()

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Do you declare the `openSettings()` and `openSearch()` methods in the same class that you declare `onOptionsItemSelected`?

Comment: No, I was just going by the docs by google, it doesn't list anything about that (or if it does, I cannot find it)

Comment: That's because it's a hint to what you should do, when the respective menu item is clicked. You will have to define your own methods, and execute the code relevant to what you would like to achieve in those situations. See my answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not defined the methods `openSettings()` and `openSearch()` inside the Activity where you define `onOptionsItemSelected`.

The result of this is that the compiler will tell you that it `cannot find symbol method openSearch()` and `cannot find symbol method openSettings()`

You simply have to add the method declaration inside the Activity:

```
private void openSettings(){
    //Execute relevant code
}

private void openSearch(){
    //Execute relevant code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above function doesn't get executed on Button pressed event. It is executed when user selected an item from menu.

At the moment, compiler doesn't know if such method signatures exist in the class. You would need to define the functions inside the class, then use them. I guess it will work fine.